# AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute 'merge_sort' and another error

Tags: python, merge, linked-list

I'm working to do Sorts a linked list by using Merge Sort.I have error when I run the Programm which is

```
x = list_linked.merge_sort(l)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'merge_sort'
```

here is my function in the file(list_l):

```
def merge_sort(a):
        a._front = merge_sort_aux(a._front)
        return
def merge_sort_aux(a)
        if a is not None and a._next:

            left, right = merge_sort_aux(a)
            left = merge_sort_aux(left)
            right = merge_sort_aux(right)
            a = merge_sort_aux(left, right)
        return a
```

here is the main:

```
from list_l import List
import list_linked
a = [3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 3, 5, 2, 5]
l = List()
for i in a:
    l.append(i)

x = list_l.merge_sort(l)
print(x)
```

also in my function I get error:

```
 Method 'merge_sort - sorts_linked' should have self as first 
   parameter
Method 'merge_sort_aux - sorts_linked' should have self as first 
 parameter
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: Based on how you are importing as `from list_l import List`. You need to also do `from list_l import List, merge_sort`. So then you just do `x = merge_sort(l)`

Comment: You are importing something called `List`. It doesn't appear that you import  `merge_sort`.

Comment: @idjaw: thanks I change it

Comment: @roadrunner66: you are right that is give me the error:  Method 'merge_sort - sorts_linked' should have self as first 
   parameter, how can I fixed?

Comment: That's a separate question.  Post a new question and close this one if it's resolved (post an answer yourself if nobody else did, then accept it when you have waited long enough).

Comment: @ tripleee: I do not get the answer yet